# Are there any JavaScript libraries that can dynamically update a table from a CSV file?

Tags: javascript

What I'm looking for is software that can poll, say every second, a CSV file on the server that I will update programmatically and render the updated contents in a browser

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/csv2table) and then call it on a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) , they have Elegant dependency tracking - automatically updates the right parts of your UI whenever your data model changes